# Error when flipping an image horizontally in Python

Tags: python, image-processing

I need to flip a picture horizontally, *without using the reverse function*, I thought I had it right but the error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    Flip("bm.gif","bm.ppm")
  File "C:\Users\....ImageProcessingSKLT.py", line 133, in Flip
    pic1 = graphics.getPixel(x,y)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getPixel'
```

The code I have is

```
def Flip(image1, image2):
    img = graphics.Image(graphics.Point(0, 0), image1)
    X = img.getWidth()
    Y = img.getHeight()
    for y in range(Y//2):
        for x in range(X):
            pic1 = graphics.getPixel(x,y)
            pic2 = graphics.setPixel(X-x,y)
            temp = graphics.getColor(pic1)
            graphics.setColor(pic1,getColor(pic2))
            graphics.setColor(pic2,temp)
            image2 = pic2
    return image2
```

What does the error mean? and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        pic1 = graphics.getPixel(x,y)
        pic2 = graphics.setPixel(X-x,y)
```

Probably should be:

```
        pic1 = img.getPixel(x,y)
        pic2 = img.setPixel(X-x,y)
```

Comment: thanks that fixed it.  Now I have a new problem (See edited question)

Answer (score 1):

The interpreter is complaining that it can't find the `getPixel` function inside the module `graphics`; it's `img.getPixel`, not `graphics.getPixel`.

Comment: thanks that fixed it.  Now I have a new problem (See edited question)

Comment: @cah: that's not how StackOverflow works. If the current problem was fixed, accept an answer and post your new problem as a separate question.

Comment: I reverted it to the original question.  @cah, you should accept one of the answers that helped you to solve the problem.